# npm package vulnerabilities explained to a beginner front-end dev, should I worry?

Tags: security, npm, web, package, frontend

I'm just starting to learn front-end and over the course of a past few months I've built a ton of basic websites using bootstrap, tailwind, react, scss, basically stuff that is either installed with npm or needs something installed with npm. And I upload those projects to a website hosting platform.

Now, I always get some warnings about vulnerabilities, ranging from moderate even to critical, and I always ignore them. The tutorials I watch usually say to ignore this and not worry about it yet. My university web dev course TAs said the same thing.

So I didn't worry about it, thought that that stuff represented the application potentially being broken or not working. And now I see that vulnerabilities represent real, security threats, potential hacks, malwares etc. I read about the coa/rs hack fiasco and got worried that I might have some projects that also can be corrupted like that because they are hosted online.

My initial thought is that these threats pose threats to the hosted websites/applications themselves and I shouldn't worry since my websites don't have real users with real passwords and stuff like that but I'm not really sure if my PC can be compromised or hacked or something like that since I also read about malware packages installing crypto miners, ransomware, etc.

I read a couple of threads here, dozen of reddit posts, 2 blog posts, one by the co-creator of React app and got a lot of conflicting advice.

There is advice to not worry about it if working on personal projects run on my machine and to not upload anything to the web, but then, is it not common to use web hosting platforms and upload stuff so you can show your work to your friends, test it on other devices, etc. ? There is advice to audit fix and update everything, then I go watch a npm tutorial where a guy says that most of developers don't respect semantic versioning and minor updates can break the API so I shouldn't update anything. There is advice to go over each vulnerability and try to understand what it means but I went to check out this [vulnerability](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-67hx-6x53-jw92) and I can't understand what any of this.

So I'm asking how to deal with all this? Should I pull down all my sites, only upload ones with no vulnerabilities? I only know about moving react stuff to dev dependencies but other than that I'm confused.